# AADSTS650052: The app needs access to a service (\"http://rts.powerapps.com\")

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'm trying to debug a RapidCMS site locally.  I use AAD to authenticate the user against my domain.  For no apparent reason I am now receiving this error when launching my app:

> Microsoft
>   Sign in
>   Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> AADSTS650052: The app needs access to a service (\"http://rts.powerapps.com\") that your organization \"REDACTED\" has not subscribed to or enabled. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions.

I've never done anything with PowerApps and cannot find any reference to it in the code or on my Azure AD applications.

Comment: Did you have any luck? I am getting this error in an App Service with Express AAD authorisation switched on.

Comment: +1 same her - exactly the same issue

Comment: +1 same here. I got this with express auth in a function app

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by removing the API permsissons to Power Apps that the express AAD authorization seems to have set up automatically for the app registration in AAD.

Found the answer here: https://github.com/shibayan/keyvault-acmebot/issues/46